# SQLAlchemy: How to add conditionally to a collection via event listener?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, I can listen for the `append` event on collections to intercept and possibly change values which are to be appended. How can I silently drop the value (not append), e.g. when I want to implement a `set`-like behaviour with arbitrary criteria?

MCVE (works without any dependency except sqlalchemy, just copy and paste):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Text

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column, ForeignKey

from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()

_next_id = 1


def get_id():
    global _next_id
    _ = _next_id
    _next_id += 1
    return _


class A1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=get_id)
    a2 = relationship('A2', back_populates='a')


class A2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=get_id)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a1.id'))
    a = relationship('A1', back_populates='a2')

    name = Column(Text)


@listens_for(A1.a2, 'append', retval=True)
def coll_listener(target, val, initiator):
    for _ in target.a2:
        if _.name == val.name:
            # this is justs some arbitrary condition to illustrate things
            return
    return val


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
_session = Session()

a2_1 = A2(name='a2_1')
a2_2 = A2(name='a2_2')
a2_3 = A2(name='a2_1')

a1 = A1()

for thing in (a2_1, a2_2, a2_3, a1):
    _session.add(thing)

_session.flush()

for a in (a2_1, a2_2, a2_3):
    a1.a2.append(a)

_session.flush()

# raises FlushError: Can't flush None value found in collection A1.a2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself here, since nobobdy has taken interest...

I now believe it's not possible to drop elements while adding *with an event listener*. So I ended up implementing a [custom collection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html?highlight=custom%20collection#custom-collection-implementations%20custom%20collection) (which is not exactly encouraged), and that turned out to be rather straightforward:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column, ForeignKey

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()

_next_id = 1


def get_id():
    global _next_id
    _ = _next_id
    _next_id += 1
    return _


class NamedThingCollection(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def __contains__(self, thing):
        return next((True for x in self.data if x.name == thing.name), False)

    def append(self, item):
        if item not in self:
            self.data.append(item)

    def remove(self, item):
        self.data.remove(item)

    def extend(self, items):
        self.data.extend(items)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


class A1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=get_id)
    a2 = relationship(
        'A2', back_populates='a', collection_class=NamedThingCollection)


class A2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=get_id)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a1.id'))
    a = relationship('A1', back_populates='a2')

    name = Column(Text)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
_session = Session()

a2_1 = A2(name='a2_1')
a2_2 = A2(name='a2_2')
a2_3 = A2(name='a2_1')

a1 = A1()

for thing in (a2_1, a2_2, a2_3, a1):
    _session.add(thing)

for a in (a2_1, a2_2, a2_3, a2_1):
    a1.a2.append(a)

_session.flush()

assert len(a1.a2) == 2
```

Of course one has to implement further behaviour as needed, e.g. `__getitem__()` / `__setitem__()` / `__delitem__()` for indexing etc.